# how to convert an image to base64 image in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am actually trying to convert an image picked by `ImagePicker` in flutter to `base64` image. I am always getting the error.

```
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 
'file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/Abid_Wipro_neemuchwala1- 
770x433.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
E/flutter ( 5042): #0      _File.throwIfError 
(dart:io/file_impl.dart:628)
E/flutter ( 5042): #1      _File.openSync 
(dart:io/file_impl.dart:472)
E/flutter ( 5042): #2      _File.readAsBytesSync 
(dart:io/file_impl.dart:532)
```

the code i am using is this one.

```
     File fileData;
   /////////////...........


      new Container(
            child: new FutureBuilder<File>(
              future: imageFile,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<File> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                    snapshot.data != null) {
                  fileData = snapshot.data;


                  return new Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      image: new DecorationImage(
                        image: new FileImage(snapshot.data,),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.error != null) {
                  return new Column(children: <Widget>[
                    centerWidget('Choose Image or Audio or Video'),
                    _circleAvatar()
                  ]);
                } else {
                  return new Column(children: <Widget>[
                    centerWidget('Choose Image or Audio or Video'),
                    _circleAvatar()
                  ]);
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
/////////////////

    File imageFile = new File(widget.fileData.uri.toString());
    List<int> imageBytes = imageFile.readAsBytesSync();
    String base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);
```

Please, can someone tell me where is it that i am making a mistake .

Many thanks,
Mahi

Comment: The file you try to read doesn't exist or the app doesn't have permission to read. The error doesn't seem related to base64

Comment: Thanks@GünterZöchbauer  but the file is present in the path specified , and is displayed on the phone but cannot convert the image to base64

Comment: It's still not related to base64 when the error says that the file can't be read.

Comment: Hi @zoechi is there any other solution so that i can just convert the image file to base64 encoding.

Comment: You can't convert something that you don't have access to :D

Comment: @zoechi i am thinking i just picked an image from gallery and want to convert the picked image to base64 is this something which we cannot do in flutter or dart?

Comment: Why do you keep talking about converting. First you need to be able to access the file and it's content. Before you are not able to do that there is absolutely no point in talking about converting.

Comment: sorry @zoechi . My requirement in the application is to take a picture or pick one from gallery and then upload this image to service which uses the sqlite database. Before sending a request I need to convert this to base64 but as from this conversation you are saying i am trying to convert something i don't have access to . I think i need to find a different solution to this one then.

Comment: ... or figure out why your app can't read from a file you claim is there. I haven't tried to read from the download directory myself yet.

Comment: the code is failing at this line ```List<int> imageBytes = imageFile.readAsBytesSync();``` . am i doing something wrong here.?

Comment: I see 2 possible issues as mentioned above. The file with the given path doesn't exist (perhaps path wrong in some way) or the app doesn't have read access. If you could render the image using an `Image` widget, then it's probably not a permission issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169832/discussion-between-mahi-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Thanks @zoechi you are amazing the path was modified, i removed the line ```File imageFile = new File(widget.fileData.uri.toString());``` and chnaged my code as ```List<int> imageBytes = widget.fileData.uri.readAsBytesSync();``` and it's working now.

Answer (score 110):

I just changed my code as follows,

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<int> imageBytes = widget.fileData.readAsBytesSync();
print(imageBytes);
String base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);
```

and this is working fine now.

It is better to read it asynchronously as the image can be very large which may cause blocking of the main thread

```
 List<int> imageBytes = await widget.fileData.readAsBytes();
```

Comment: from where did you get the function `base64Encode()` ?

Comment: hi @ArnoldParge it's from ```dart: convert``` API if you want to check it out.

Comment: This gives the error in postman:The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

Answer (score 33):

If you import the `io` package and convert:

```dart
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'dart:convert';
```

you can simply change the image to string :

```dart
final bytes = io.File(imageBytes.path).readAsBytesSync();

String img64 = base64Encode(bytes);
```

Comment: what is Io ? which package import here ?

Comment: import 'dart:io' as Io;  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/dart-io-library.html

Answer (score 13):

In my case, i first selected the image using [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) then use these line of code to convert the image to base64.

```
 final bytes = File(image!.path).readAsBytesSync();
                          String base64Image =  "data:image/png;base64,"+base64Encode(bytes);

                          print("img_pan : $base64Image");
```

image_picker code :

```
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  XFile? image;

                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.h))
                    ),
                    child:InkWell(
                    onTap: () async {
                      image = await _picker.pickImage(
                          source: ImageSource.gallery);
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    child: image != null
                        ? Image.file(
                            File(image!.path),
                            height: 100.h,
                            width: 100.w,
                          )
                        : Image.asset(
                            'assets/image_icon.png',
                            height: 100.h,
                            width: 100.w,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),
                  ),),
```

Comment: The header "data:image/png;base64," made my code work. Thanks!

Comment: will this work with jpg files also? or just for png

Comment: @msalihbindak just change the string from "data:image/png;" to "data:image/jpeg;" that will make it work.

Answer (score 3):

In case you are trying to manage image/file uploads using Flutter Web, https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker is a better package to go with.

As we know, `dart:io` is not supported on Flutter Web and throws `Unsupported operation: _Namespace` error. Hence, using `File` and reading file's bytes was not an option. Luckily, the package provides API to convert the uploaded image to `Uint8List`. Here is my implementation:

```
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';

...

FilePickerResult? pickedFile;

...

void chooseImage() async {
    pickedFile = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      try {
        setState(() {
          logoBase64 = pickedFile!.files.first.bytes;
        });
      } catch (err) {
        print(err);
      }
    } else {
      print('No Image Selected');
    }
}
```

In case you need to display the local image right away, use `Image.memory`.

```
Image.memory(logoBase64!);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Container(
                            child: new GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () async {
                                FocusScope.of(context)
                                    .requestFocus(new FocusNode());
                                await getImage();
                              },
                              child: new Center(
                                child: _image == null
                                    ? new Stack(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          new Center(
                                            child: new CircleAvatar(
                                              radius: 80.0,
                                              backgroundColor:
                                                  const Color(0xFF778899),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          new Center(
                                            child: Icon(
                                              Icons.perm_identity,
                                              size: 120,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      )
                                    : new CircleAvatar(
                                        radius: 60,
                                        child: ClipOval(
                                          child: Align(
                                            heightFactor: 0.8,
                                            widthFactor: 1.0,
                                            child: new Image.file(_image),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

Future getImage() async {
    UserService userRestSrv = UserService();

    PickedFile image = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 50);

    if (image != null) {
      setState(() {
        _image = File(image.path);
      });

      final bytes = File(image.path).readAsBytesSync();

      String img64 = base64Encode(bytes);
      var responseProfileImage = await userRestSrv.updateImage(userId, img64);

      if (responseProfileImage != null && responseProfileImage.data['ResponseCode'] == "00")
        showMessage('Profile Image not uploaded', false);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here a simple function:

```
String convertIntoBase64(File file) {
List<int> imageBytes = file.readAsBytesSync();
String base64File = base64Encode(imageBytes);
return base64File;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that more than one has already answered the question.
But I allow myself to put my solution and it works for me.
I use `file_picker: ^5.0.1`

```
void openFileImageExplorer() async {
    //try {
      final pickedFile = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
          allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp', 'gif']
      );
      if (pickedFile == null) {
        return;
      }

    final file = pickedFile.files.first;

    final bytes = File(file.path!).readAsBytesSync();
    String img64 = base64Encode(bytes);
    setState(() {
      imageBase64 = img64;
    });

    logCat(img64);
    //} catch(ex, trace ){
    //  logError(ex, trace: trace);
    //}
}
```

And to display the image

```
Image.memory( base64Decode(imageBase64), fit: BoxFit.cover )
```

and I hope it will help...

Answer (score 0):

```
//this is dart code
final bytes = File(image!.path).readAsBytesSync();  
String base64Image = base64Encode(bytes);
print("imgbytes : $base64Image");

//this is flutter code for image picker
Future uploadAll() async {
var bytes = File(image!.path).readAsBytesSync();
String base64Image = base64Encode(bytes);
print('upload proccess started');

var apipostdata = {
  "title": contentController.text.toString().toUpperCase(),
  "book_image": base64Image,
  "book_type": _genderRadioBtnVal,
};
await http
    .post(Uri.parse('http://192.168.29.111:8000/api/book/add_book'),
        body: apipostdata)
    .then((response) {
  var returndata = jsonEncode(response.body);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(returndata);
  } else {
    print('failed');
  }
}).catchError((err) {
  setState(() {
    err;
  });
});  }
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation. Don't just post the code. See [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
String imagepath = " /data/user/img.jpg"; 
//image path, you can get it with image_picker package

File imagefile = File(imagepath); //convert Path to File
Uint8List imagebytes = await imagefile.readAsBytes(); //convert to bytes
String base64string = base64.encode(imagebytes); //convert bytes to base64 string
print(base64string);
```

I achieve this in that way

Answer (score -1):

try to use `Content-Type:charset=utf-8`

in my case i use  `"Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8"` in header of my api

```
http.post(
        Uri.parse(url),
        body: myBody,
        headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8"},
      );
```

and  `var baseEncode= base64Encode(await file.readAsBytes());` for encoding

and it works for me