# Conversion of base64 image to file flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, base64

I need to convert screenshot of flutter app to file. I worked on that and I converted screenshot to base64 image. But I blocked in converting base64 to file. Any solutions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert base64 to image and save it in temp folder flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61996560/convert-base64-to-image-and-save-it-in-temp-folder-flutter)

Comment: See this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52606300/how-to-save-base64-string-to-file-and-view-it-using-flutter

Answer (score 0):

Greeting

Use this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/file_support

its very helpful tool for managing file handling operations on flutter for mobile platform

```
await getFileFromBase64(String base64);
```