# Storing image in MongoDB Database

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart

How can I store images in a MongoDB through Flutter/Dart?

We are developing an android application using MongoDB and Flutter. We want to store images during the registration of users in our app. I already referred the **mongo-dart** documentation but still, I can't find any solution about this.

Comment: IMO, Convert & store as `base64` would be better option.

Comment: Ya It works. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest encoding your images to [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) format. Then you can store them technically as plain text. There is a **base64Encode** function in **dart:convert** package.

You can also check this discussion: [how to convert an image to base64 image in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50036393/how-to-convert-an-image-to-base64-image-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB has [`GridFS`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) for storing files:

> A convention for storing large files in a MongoDB database. All of the official MongoDB drivers support this convention, as does the mongofiles program.

It *looks* like mongo-dart [supports it](https://github.com/mongo-dart/mongo_dart/blob/master/test/gridfs_test.dart) as well although it's missing the documentation.

Comment: Is there any blog, or documentation now available for gridfs in mongo-dart?