# Future<Uint8List> to Base64 or PNG in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, cross-platform

I need to convert a `Future<Uint8List>` to Base64 or PNG in Flutter, I am using [this pub](https://pub.dev/packages/signature) to get signature and export it but when I call `toPngBytes()` method (method in pub) it returns a `Future<Uint8List>` and I need to convert it to `Base64` format or `List<int>` at least `ByteData` format, I can not convert it to a more usable format for me, can anyone help me to resolve this.

```
_controller.toPngBytes(); // _controller is a variable that holds info about my signature.
```

Comment: what is wrong with `Uint8List`?

Comment: Basicly not usefull in my case

Comment: and `ByteData` is more useful? if so, use [ByteData.sublistView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-typed_data/ByteData/ByteData.sublistView.html) constructor

Comment: Actually `List<int>` is a lot more useful for me to use `base64Encode()`, I am not familiar with ` ByteData.sublistView` can you give an example for my case please?

Comment: *"Actually List<int> is a lot more useful for me "* - [Uint8List](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-typed_data/Uint8List-class.html) is a `List<int>` - see `Implemented types` it the link i posted

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

// async variant
final imageData = await _controller.toPngBytes(); // must be called in async method
final imageEncoded = base64.encode(imageData); // returns base64 string

// callback variant
_controller.toPngBytes().then((data) {
 final imageEncoded = base64.encode(data); 
});
```

Comment: Of courese I tried it but it is not appliciable because `toPngBytes()` returns  `Future<Uint8List>` but `base64Encode()` takes paremeter type `List<int>`

Comment: Did you read the comments? Do you know what is async/await? Update answer.

Comment: Yes, I read them but I did not understand why I should call it in async method but now, I understand it thanks for helping, now I know how to use Future variables.

Comment: how to convert Uint8List to Image dataType.

Comment: It's also not worked, I would use this method for FTPConnect Pub , but if I use as File(encodedImage) will be not possible, have u got any idea about the FtpConnect as Signature Upload to Hosting via Ftp , it must be export as a File . Thx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61928845/11104759

Answer (score 6):

This function made me upload an image to [Xano](https://docs.xano.com/working-with-data/functions/content-upload) correctly:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';

String uint8ListTob64(Uint8List uint8list) {
  String base64String = base64Encode(uint8list);
  String header = "data:image/png;base64,";
  return header + base64String;
}
```

You can transform an image into Uint8List in the following way:

```
String path = "image.png";
File file = File(path);
Uint8List uint8list = file.readAsBytesSync();
//or
Uint8List uint8list = await file.readAsBytes();
```