# Using Flutter Camera package, how do I convert a photo to a base64 string?

Tags: flutter, camera

Using the [Flutter Camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) package (v0.9.4+5), how do I convert a captured photo into a base64 string?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following code will work, but welcome to any thoughts on how the code can be improved.

```dart
import 'dart:convert' as convert;

void capturePhoto() async {

  // Note: `controller` being initialized as shown in readme
  // https://pub.dev/packages/camera#example

  XFile photo = await controller.takePicture();
  List<int> photoAsBytes = await photo.readAsBytes();
  String photoAsBase64 = convert.base64Encode(photoAsBytes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    final bytes = Io.File(image.path).readAsBytesSync();
    String img64 = base64Encode(bytes);
    print (img64);
```

Comment: I'm looking to capture a photo directly from the camera, without saving it to the image library. I think your answer fits this question instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50036393/how-to-convert-an-image-to-base64-image-in-flutter