# How to store Image in Shared Preference - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, imagepicker

I'm trying to store image (picked from ImagePicker) in shared preferences, so I can persist the data

This is what I did so far

Here is the code

```
  File? profileImage;

  void saveData(String key, String value) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString(key, value);
  }

  Future pickProfile() async {
     final profileImagePicker = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

     final directoryPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
     final path = directoryPath.path;
     final imageFile = await File(profileImagePicker!.path).copy('$path/image1.png');

     saveData('primaryProfile', imageFile.toString()); // Store it as a string, don't know if this is the right away


     setState(() {
       profileImage = imageFile;
     });
  }

  void getPrimaryProfile() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final value = prefs.getString('primaryProfile'); // How can I convert this to File object from String, so I can assign it to file object (profileImage)


  }

  //To display the image

  CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: profileImage != null ? FileImage(profileImage!) as ImageProvider : const AssetImage('assets/images/profile.png'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.black45
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) for this. Images are stored as binary files, which is a sequence of bytes. So what base64 does is that it converts your bytes into a long string that expresses this data. Its problem is that it takes more memory than the actual image. It can make the file size more than 25% of its size.

Shared Preferences also exist in java android and it is not advised to store images in shared preferences. [Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8586243/13742330) an android geek telling this. Maybe you would consider changing this part of your app's design.

For Flutter, [base64](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/base64Encode.html) are there.  And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50038239/13742330) is an example on how to use it.