# How to convert users signature to base64 encoding in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, signaturepad

I'm using the `syncfusion_flutter_signaturepad` package to let the user input their signature. Now, what I'm trying to achieve is to convert that signature to base64 format for our API. Here's what I have.

```
GlobalKey<SfSignaturePadState> _signaturePadKey = GlobalKey();
.....

final signatureData = await _signaturePadKey.currentState!.toImage();
final image = await signatureData.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);

if (image != null) {
  final imageBytes = image.buffer.asUint8List();
  final decodedImage = img.decodeImage(imageBytes);
  //String encodedSignature = base64.encode(decodedImage); //decodedImage error The argument type 'Image?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<int>'.
  print('Base64 encoded string: $decodedImage');
}
```

Printed result is

```
Base64 encoded string: Instance of 'Image'
```

I also tried this way but it's still not working.

```
ui.Image signatureData =
    await _signaturePadKey.currentState!.toImage();
ByteData? byteData = await signatureData.toByteData(
    format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
String imageEncoded =
    base64.encode(byteData!.buffer.asUint8List());

print("Encoded: $imageEncoded");
```

Result is :

```
Encoded: 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
```

That when I try to test it in [online converter](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter), it's not working.

**EDIT** Added mimetype:

```
String imageEncoded = "data:image/png;base64," +
                  base64.encode(byteData!.buffer.asUint8List());
```

But it's only a blank page, the signature is not there at all.

**RESULT:**

```
Encoded: data:image/png;base64,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
```

Am I on the right track on trying to get the desired result?
How can I attain my goal using the `syncfusion_flutter_signaturepad` flutter package?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to convert an image to base64 image in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50036393/how-to-convert-an-image-to-base64-image-in-flutter)

Comment: @OMiShah Thank you, but that one was using image picker while mine here is I'm using signature pad. I'm not sure if toImage creates temp file path for the signature and how I can I possibly access if it does.

Comment: you are missing prefix of mimetype...

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj Oh thanks for that one! But when I try to save it, it's just blank page, no signature at all .

Comment: It is normal, base64 functionality is that without a specific output.

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj Oh! So if I convert it back to image, it will be just a blank image? Without the signature?

Comment: I'm going to post an answer with utilities that you can use to do the correct conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh! Might be helpful to anyone, conversion is working fine, my default here is that I relied on the `printdebug` value. This one did not display all converted data so I have to add a temporary textfield to display generated value.

```
TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

//under save button
// ......
String imageEncoded = await "data:image/png;base64," +
                      base64.encode(byteData!.buffer.asUint8List());
_textEditingController.text = imageEncoded;

TextField(
  controller: _textEditingController,
  //this one holds all the necessary encryped data
),
```

Hope this one might help someone!

Answer (score 2):

You can use those method as utilities to convert images to base64 and viceversa.

Calling `imageToByteData`(passing a drawing image as parameter) then calling `uint8ListTobase64String`(passing data got before by previous method).

Anyway in comments you will find what is used for each method. I think those methods might be prototypes from which you can start to improve, based on your needs!

```
  import 'dart:ui' as UI;
  import 'package:image/image.dart' as drawing;
  import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart'; 

  // Then on your class... where inside are:

  // Convert byte-data to base64
  static String uint8ListTobase64String(Uint8List? data) =>
      data != null ? base64Encode(data) : "";
  
  // Convert base64 string to byte-data as Uint8List
  static Uint8List? base64StringToUint8List(String base64String) =>
      (base64String.isNotEmpty) ? base64Decode(base64String) : null;

  // Widget Image from a base64 string 
  static Image imageFromBase64String(String base64String) =>
        Image.memory(base64Decode(base64String));

  // Passing a "drawing" image as parameter then convert it in a well-encoded image and return byte-data as Uint8List
  static Future<Uint8List?> imageToByteData(drawing.Image imageSource) async {
    try {
      UI.Codec codec = await UI.instantiateImageCodec(drawing.encodePng(imageSource));
      UI.FrameInfo frameInfo = await codec.getNextFrame();
      ByteData? data = await frameInfo.image.toByteData(format: UI.ImageByteFormat.png);
      return data!.buffer.asUint8List();
    } catch (e) {
   //log(e.toString());
    }

    return null;
  }
```

Take in mind here is used also `image.dart` package. You can find more info about it here: https://pub.dev/packages/image. But, that doesn't mean all cannot be done without it..

Comment: Thanks for this. From what I've understood from imageToByteData is that it uses image path? If so, what I'm using here is from the signature of the user then directly convert it to base 64 encoding.

Comment: imageToByteData  use an Image as parameter by  (package image.dart you can find it in flutter packages repo) . Anyway get your test, using parts that what you need

Comment: I see. This line of code `drawing.encodePng(imageSource)` showing an error `The argument type 'List<int>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'`

Comment: Who List<int> is coming from? Convert it directly as Uint8List before you will pass it... OR USE : `Uint8List.fromList(yourListHere)`

Comment: I have no idea where it came from, I just copied your code to test it and that line highlights with error.

Comment: That because of your flutter version maybe. Use as I wrote in comment  `Uint8List.fromList(yourListHere)`